# How to disable right click on whole website (not just a few pages) in Angular

Tags: angular

I have tried to search for solutions which would allow me to disable right click on the whole application in Angular 2+ but I get only solutions for disabling on few components like,

```
<someSelector appDisableRightClick></someSelector>
```

where, someSelector is any element of HTML, appDisableRightClick is a directive to disable right click using hostlistener for contextmenu event.

The problem with this is it will have to be written everywhere which means if I want to disable right click everywhere in my application, this is not something I should be looking for. Need a little help here please for the optimum solution to achieve this for the whole application.

Comment: you can post this in answer section

Comment: Thank You. Happy that the answer worked for you.  It will be great if you  would support me back. Thank You again. I am also available to work more. connect with me by email id `grdtechlab@gmail.com`

Comment: @GRD Request you to please put your comment in answer section so that I can accept it and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo in this [Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvmcrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisable-right-click.service.ts)

Basically need to access document object inside angular service using injection token of document, so that its safe way to access dom using document inside angular. below is service code

```
export class DisableRightClickService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
  disableRightClick() {
    this.document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) =>
      event.preventDefault()
    );
  }
}
```

In above code we are adding contextmenu event to document and at the same time we prevent event to occur too!. Now, need to add this inside app.component.ts file like below..

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(private rightClickDisable: DisableRightClickService) {}
 ngOnInit() {
   this.rightClickDisable.disableRightClick();
 } 
}
```

This way you can disable right click for your whole application.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @GRD, the below link provides a good and acceptable solution for the problem. Asked him to put comment in answers section, but he didn't, need to close this question, so putting it myself here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvmcrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Could you include the relevant code in your answer?

Comment: Please see answer added by @GRD. Thanks.